# Apply for NSF postdoc in mathematics: question about SAM

Tags: funding, postdocs, nsf

I am applying for the mathematics NSF postdoc, and when I click check, I get the warning:

Organization-DUNS Conflict - The identified organization cannot be found in the System for Award Management (SAM) as the organization is either: (1) not registered in SAM or (2) the record in FastLane Research Administration (including the DUNS number and address) does not match the data in SAM. Proposers are required to register in SAM prior to proposal submission. Failure to complete the SAM registration process prior to proposal submission may impact the processing of the proposal.

However, it will still let me submit.  Do I need to register in SAM?  I am not really sure how to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you contacted the sponsored research office at the organization you have identified? Universities employ people specifically to make sure this kind of thing is in order. If you don't know whom to contact, you could first ask your sponsoring scientist -- h/she will know who the right people to ask are.

Comment: It sounds as though the problem is that the university you've identified has not gotten their information into the "System for Award Management" (or some of the SAM data is incorrect) and thus it won't accept your application.  If that's the case, only the sponsored research office at the university can fix it.

Comment: It says it will accept the submission though.  It just warns me there might be a delay.  You are supposed to put yourself as the organization.  But for DUNS number you are supposed to enter a generic number with all 1's.  So I am unsure if I should ignore the message or not.  I would think anyone applying for NSF postdocs would be receiving the same message.  I only get the message if I click on ``check.''

Comment: "I am unsure..." Please ask the university's sponsored research office, and/or technical staff at the NSF, as they're the only ones who will know for sure. This is a great question, but an internet forum is not the best place to ask it.